# How to insert data using php when there is unique data in the string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some data manually in the wordpress table but whenever i run my query it gives me this error:--

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in /home/yogi/public_html/shontp/wp-content/themes/bridge-child/jut-login.php on line 19
```

This is the code to insert query:--

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ssdcu_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '15', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}')";

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: A decent IDE would make this error very apparent to you.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ssdcu_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '15', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}')";
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ssdcu_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES (NULL, '15', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";s:1:\"1\";}')";
```